# How to keep the text behind the first image whenever the window is resized?

Tags: html, css

```html
<html>
<head>
<title> Example </title>
<style>
img:hover {opacity : 0.3;}
img {z-index : 1;
height : 33%;
width : 33%;

}
.first { position : absolute;
 top: 0%;
 left: 0%;}
 .second {position : absolute;
 top: 0%;
 left: 33%;}
 .third {position : absolute;
 top: 0%;
 left: 66%;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
This text should remain behind 1st image on resizing the window.
<img class = "first" src = "http://www.dubcen.com/uploads/ex.jpg">
<img class = "second" src = "http://www.dubcen.com/uploads/ex.jpg">
<img class = "third" src = "http://www.dubcen.com/uploads/ex.jpg">

</body>
</html>​
```

How to keep this text behind the first image only? I tried working out with div's but could not achieve anything concrete.

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: On what width in pixels you would like changing in the style of the element? And what do you mean by behind the picture - currently the text is behind the 3 pictures? And lastly if you want some changes to the text please wrap the text in a tag element - for example in `p` : `<p>This text should remain behind 1st image on resizing the window.</p>`

Comment: @ViktorMaksimov if you open the preview in full window, the text is behind one image only otherwise on small enough width and height of window it could take 2 lines as well.. And then, I tried to use `<div>` but could not find any solution..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add position: absolute for your first image and put everything in 3 separate boxes. Than type text only into first box. Check fiddle link.

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
```

Here is a possible solution: https://jsfiddle.net/c4oz41nu/

Let me know if this helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is wrong as well as the css.

You shouldn`t use position absolute as you did in your example.

Here is the updated code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="imgHolder">
    <p>This text should remain behind 1st image on resizing the window.</p>
    <img src="http://www.dubcen.com/uploads/ex.jpg">
</div>
<div class="imgHolder"><img src="http://www.dubcen.com/uploads/ex.jpg"></div>
<div class="imgHolder"><img src="http://www.dubcen.com/uploads/ex.jpg"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
 img:hover {opacity : 0.3}
.imgHolder{float:left;width:33%;white-space: normal;position:relative}
.imgHolder p{position:absolute;top:0;display:none}
.imgHolder:hover p{display:block}
```

It should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Example </title>
<style>
img:hover {
    opacity : 0.3;
}
img {
    height : 33%;
    width : 33%;
}
.first {
    z-index: 1;
    position : fixed;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;}
 .second {
    z-index: 0;
    position : absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 33%;
 }
 .third {
    z-index: 0;
    position : absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 66%;
 }
 p{
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p class="text">This text should remain behind 1st image on resizing the window</p>
<img class = "first" src = "http://www.dubcen.com/uploads/ex.jpg">
<img class = "second" src = "http://www.dubcen.com/uploads/ex.jpg">
<img class = "third" src = "http://www.dubcen.com/uploads/ex.jpg">
</body>
</html>​
```

I inserted a `<p>` tag for the text and then gave it a z-index of 0.
Then each image except the first one also a z-index of 0.
The first image has a z-index of 1. 
The p tag is absolutely positioned and will always stay behind the first image. Even after resizing but not behind the second or the third image.
Hope this helps :)

Comment: I am sorry if I could not explain my problem correctly, but see Dejan's answer.. It is what I required..